# Why fashion mnist is treated as mnist in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I'm trying to load fashion mnist dataset into my spyder. I'm trying to do this using code:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
fmnist = input_data.read_data_sets('data/fashion', 
                                   source_url='http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/')
```

However, instead of loading fashion mnist it loads mnist dataset:

For example by running code

```
plt.imshow(fmnist.train.images[5].reshape(28,28))
```

I obtain image:

[image]

Could you please give me a hand where do I have mistake?

Answer (score 0):

How about just getting the data from [keras datasets](https://keras.io/api/datasets/fashion_mnist/) like this?

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```